# No navigation between different views

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, navigation, spring-webflow

I have two views in my app which are two tabs and i'm trying to add a button on the first tab to open the second tab so i wrote this in my flow.xml but i still have errors when i click in the button.

Here's the flow.xml:

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd"
       start-state="vue1">

     <view-state id="vue1" view="zf1/vue1">

         <on-entry>
             <evaluate expression="cu1formaction.setupForm"/>
             <evaluate expression="cu1formaction.preparerMethodeAnalyse1"/>
         </on-entry>
         <transition on="bouton1" to="accueil"/>
         <transition on="bouton2" to="#{vue2}"/>

     </view-state> 
     <end-state id="accueil" view="accueil"/>  

     <subflow-state id="bouton2" subflow="bouton2">
     <transition on="bouton2" to="vue2" />
     </subflow-state>

     <bean-import resource="cu1-flow-beans.xml"/> 
</flow>
```

and here are the errors:

Pile d'exception :

```
    org.springframework.webflow.definition.registry.FlowDefinitionConstructionException: An exception occurred constructing the flow 'cu1-flow'
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.DefaultFlowHolder.assembleFlow(DefaultFlowHolder.java:111)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.DefaultFlowHolder.getFlowDefinition(DefaultFlowHolder.java:84)
at org.springframework.webflow.definition.registry.FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl.getFlowDefinition(FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl.java:60)
at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:138)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:238)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at fr.gouv.finances.lombok.apptags.table.filter.CpAbstractExportFilter.doFilter(CpAbstractExportFilter.java:70)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at fr.gouv.finances.lombok.securite.springsecurity.SessionExpirationFilter.doFilter(SessionExpirationFilter.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.FlowBuilderException: Unable to get the model for this flow
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.model.FlowModelFlowBuilder.doInit(FlowModelFlowBuilder.java:154)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.support.AbstractFlowBuilder.init(AbstractFlowBuilder.java:46)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.FlowAssembler.assembleFlow(FlowAssembler.java:90)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.DefaultFlowHolder.assembleFlow(DefaultFlowHolder.java:109) ... 60 more Caused by: org.springframework.webflow.engine.model.builder.FlowModelBuilderException: Could not parse the XML flow definition document
at ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/flows/composantinfoutil/zf1/cu1-flow.xml]
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.model.builder.xml.XmlFlowModelBuilder.init(XmlFlowModelBuilder.java:120)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.model.builder.DefaultFlowModelHolder.assembleFlowModel(DefaultFlowModelHolder.java:87)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.model.builder.DefaultFlowModelHolder.getFlowModel(DefaultFlowModelHolder.java:61)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.model.FlowModelFlowBuilder.doInit(FlowModelFlowBuilder.java:151) ... 63 more Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 37; Open quote is expected for attribute "to" associated with an element type "transition".
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
```

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

The exception in the stack trace refers to a issue, supposedly with the quotes after "to" in your transition. It needs to be an "open" quote.

Is it possible your are using the wrong type of quote? Or the french quotes?

Please check for those possible errors